# Why my dispatch function in Redux gets a function instead of an action?

Tags: redux, dispatch

There is such kind of code that I have:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  historyData: getHistoryForSavedVariants(state)[ownProps.savedVariant.variantId],
  isHistoryLoading: getHistoryLoading(state),
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  loadData: () => {

-----> dispatch(loadHistoryForSavedVariant(ownProps.savedVariant))

  },  
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HistoryButton)
```

In another file `loadHistoryForSavedVariant` is the following:

```
export const loadHistoryForSavedVariant = (savedVariant) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_HISTORY })
    const url = `/api/saved_variant/${savedVariant.variantId}/saved_variant_history`
    new HttpRequestHelper(url,
      (responseJson) => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_HISTORY })
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_DATA, updatesById: responseJson })
      },  
      (e) => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_HISTORY })
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_DATA, error: e.message, updatesById: {} })
      },  
    ).get({ xpos: savedVariant.xpos, ref: savedVariant.ref, alt: savedVariant.alt, familyGuid: savedVariant.familyGuids[0] })
  }
}
```

So, as can be seen `dispatch` ultimately gets a function - `(dispatch) => {...}` and ***not an action***. Why? I don't understand how that works. On `Redux` official webpage I see everwhere that `dispatch` gets an `action` and not a function, so I am confused. The code is, of course, working fine, I am just interested in this particular mechanism, in whats happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a "thunk function".  Thunks are a Redux middleware that allow you to pass functions into `dispatch()`, which is useful for writing async logic separate from your components.

For more details, see these Redux tutorials:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic